# How to enable migrations for multiple databases, but one context?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6.1

> Environment:
>
> > Entity Framework 6.1.0
> >     .NET 4.5

Hi, I already have migrations enabled on my project. But I want to be able to update different databases with the same context. Is it possible? From all I researched, people are looking either for multiple contexts on one database or multiple contexts on multiple databases. What I need is one context on multiple databases.
This is my scenario:

```
development_db
production_db
```

I want to be able to apply the changes to my `development_db` and then, after everything is tested, I want to run the same update-database command for the `production_db`. I already have the 2 connection strings (for both databases) but I don't know to make it work, since the migration files would be one for the whole migrations project.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I work, I configure the context in my development environment in

web.config

```
<add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLDev2008R2;Initial Catalog=My_DEV;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=240" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I then use [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) to transform that connection string when I publish a production build

web.Release.config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyContext"
    connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=My_PROD;Integrated Security=True"
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>

</connectionStrings>
```

I allow, when the application runs in Production, for migrations to be automatically applied.  You configure this option with `Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations` (plus the other appropriate parameters).

This may be unsuitable for some environments.  If that is the case, before you run `update-database` in your development environment, first run `update-database -Script` (with appropriate parameters).  That will generate a SQL Script that you can run in your production database when you are ready to apply the given update, rather than relying on automatic migrations.

Comment: For now I'll take the `-Script` approach, but I'll study the first one. Thanks for your reply!